# How to access content of leaflet popups

Tags: html, popup, leaflet

I am creating a leaflet-popup as set of html elements:

```
var popupBox = document.createElement('div'); 
$(popupBox)
.addClass('popup-box') 
.attr("id", "mypopup");

var popupBoxContent = document.createElement('div'); 
$(popupBoxContent)
.addClass('some-class')
.html('foo')
.appendTo(popupBox);    

myLeafletObject.bindPopup(popupBox);
```

Unfortunatly i am not able to access this elements later on. For example trying to do:

`$('popup').append(someNewHTMLElement)`

fails. Can somebody help?

Comment: Of course i ment to say: $('#mypopup').append(someNewHTMLElement) fails (That $('popup')... brings no result is obviously clear)

Comment: Are you adding these popups dynamically? After the page has loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [leaflet how to make dynamic picture popup using js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923653/leaflet-how-to-make-dynamic-picture-popup-using-js)